# Why does my site enter a blank page after the form submits a post request?

Tags: python, html, django

I am using Django to create a form that will update a list. I know it's quite simple, but I haven't used it in a while and got stuck.

Here is my urls.py file inside my app:

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("<str:site>", views.info, name="info"),
]
```

Here is the views.py file:

```
from .models import website, members
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse

def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        named = request.POST["name"]
        desc = request.POST["description"]
        obj = website(name = named, description = desc)
        obj.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
    return render(request, 'management/index.html', {
        "website":website.objects.all()
    })

def info(request, site):
    return render(request, 'management/info.html', {
        site:"site"
    })
```

And here is the index.html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>
            WebGo Management
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Welcome to WebGo.</h1>
        <h3>Here, you can manage projects and deal with admins</h3>
        <form action="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
            <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" id="#">
        </form>
        <ul>
            {% for i in website %}
            <li>{{i.name}}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

After it finishes submitting the form, it takes me to a blank page, with the following URL:
http://127.0.0.1:8000/management/post?csrfmiddlewaretoken=HQO4pZAh79Q3ZUSxp90z6pRO6ieOeWI2hiBkVBu8TXaMJ63vZR2rDFskGw5oqdxr&name=Mukesh&description=cool&submit=Submit

I am confused as to why this is happening. Could someone please tell me which file is the problem and how I could fix it? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You swapped the `action` and `method` attributes:

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name">
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="#">
</form>
```

Instead it was making a GET request to the view with *relative* path `post`.

---

> **Note**: It is better to use a [**`Form`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/forms/)
> than to perform manual validation and cleaning of the data. A `Form` will not
> only simplify *rendering* a form in HTML, but it also makes it more convenient
> to *validate* the input, and *clean* the data to a more convenient type.